# YUI3 custom async events not working on Y.Global

Tags: javascript, yui3, custom-events

I am trying implement async event leveraging [YUI3 library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event-custom/#configs). So the application had been notified about event passed even with late subscription, simular like load or ready events do.

[Here it is](http://jsbin.com/ibubaq/1/edit) what I have so far, but no luck around.

```
YUI().use('event', 'event-custom', function(Y){

  function onCustomEvent () {
    Y.Global.on('custom:event', function(){
      alert('custom fired');
    });
  }
  window.setTimeout(onCustomEvent, 2000);
});

YUI().use('event', 'event-custom', function(Y){

  Y.publish('custom:event', {
    emitFacade: true,
    broadcast: 2,
    fireOnce: true,
    async: true
  });

  function fireCustomEvent () {
    Y.Global.fire('custom:event');
  }
  window.setTimeout(fireCustomEvent, 1000);
});
```

If anyone could give a hint what's wrong with this code? Thank you.

UPD:

After a bit investigations it turns out that [async events work](http://jsbin.com/ibubaq/5/edit) fine inside one `use()` instance and when not using `Global` broadcasting. So that's something either bug or limitation. Still discovering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, at the high level the inconsistency with global events (how I understood it) lays in the sandbox nature of Y object. So at some point you could fire only sync events globally cause async parameters you `subscribe` to custom event made on Y instance and not passed further (and than YUI uses some defaults or whatever). This possibly makes sense but than why such kind of events should be fireable globally? Either I miss some substantial part of YUI and this is candidate for bug report.

Anyway I do not have time to dive deeper in YUI and [what I really practically need](http://jsbin.com/ibubaq/10/edit) could be wrapped in 40 lines of code:

```
YUI.add('async-pubsub', function(Y) {
  var subscribers = {};

  if ( !YUI.asyncPubSub ) {
    YUI.namespace('asyncPubSub');
    YUI.asyncPubSub = (function(){
      var eventsFired = {};
      function doPublishFor(name) {
        var subscriber;

        for ( subscriber in subscribers ) {
          if ( subscriber === name ) {
            (subscribers[name]).call();
            delete ( subscribers[name] ); // Keep Planet clean
          }  
        }
      }
      return {
        'publish': function(name, options) {
          eventsFired[name] = options || {};
          doPublishFor(name);
        },
        'subscribe': function(name, callback) {
          if ( subscribers[name] ) {
            Y.log('More than one async subscriber per instance, overriding it.', 'warning', 'async-pubsub');
          }
          subscribers[name] = callback || function() {};
          if ( eventsFired[name] ) {
            window.setTimeout(
              function () {
                doPublishFor(name);
              },0
            );
          }
        }
      };  
    })();
  }
  Y.asyncPubSub = YUI.asyncPubSub;
}, '1.0', {requires: []});
```

There is some limitation and room for optimization here, like ability subscribe only one action for one event per `use` instance, but I do not need more. I will also try to [debug and enhance this snippet](https://gist.github.com/dmi3y/6213987) in future if there will be interest.

Still curious about YUI behavior, is it bug or something?